# Spring import views from another project

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have one webapp (with spring-mvc and thymeleaf) and one module (spring-mvc) but this module is shared between 2 different teams,Is it possible to put some html files in this module and then resolve this views from my webapp? if so how to do it ?

Please find the JavaConfig file below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {PortalApplication.class}, includeFilters = @Filter(Controller.class), useDefaultFilters = false)
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SOURCE = "/WEB-INF/i18n/messages";
    private static final String VIEWS = "/WEB-INF/views/";

    private static final String RESOURCES_LOCATION = "/resources/";
    private static final String IMAGES_LOCATION = "/resources/images";
    private static final String RESOURCES_HANDLER = RESOURCES_LOCATION + "**";`
  ...
    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix(VIEWS);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }`
```

but i cannot figure out how to add the other project relative path to a new resolver

i'm kinda lost here, such help needed, much thanks, many doge...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have you other project in the classpath of your application, and your artefact can use them and had them to your resolver as well.

Regards,

FT

Answer (score 0):

You just need a ViewResolver that does not rely solely on the ServletContext, but also resolves from Classpath (using Springs Resource framework). 
I highly suspect there is a classpath-aware ViewResolver somewhere in the MVC.